# Aligning twice in eqnarray

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I do have the following equations wich are aligned on the equal sign. Would it be possible to also align them on the R?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  \delta O_{1x} &=& R \, ^E\omega_x \, \delta t \nonumber \\
  \delta O_{1y} &=& - R \, ^E\omega_y \, \delta t \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `eqnarray`, you should use the environments provided by the `amsmath` package (refer to [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/), by Lars Madsen); here's an option using `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \delta O_{1x} &= & R \, ^E\omega_x \, \delta t \\
  \delta O_{1y} &= - &R \, ^E\omega_y \, \delta t 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And (as _you_ know, but I just wanted to point this out) if you use the `*` version, you don't need the `\nonumber`s.

Comment: @Andrew: I was just editing my answer when you wrote your comment ;-)

Comment: "Speedy fingers", that's me!  Nah, I was half way through typing an answer when yours appeared so I _had_ to find _something_ wrong with it.

Comment: @Andrew: That's one of the most awful moments in this site: when in the middle of writting your own answer you see the dreadful message announcing that another answer has been posted.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys and for letting me know that eqnarray is bad!